# Android cannot resolve sybmol getFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-sliding

I am using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) to create sliding menu for application but I get error in the following lines, and I am unable to solve it:

```
getFragmentManager();
getActionBar();
```

After adding `AppCompat` to project many problems can resolve.

My Manifes:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

My class extends from `Activity`. After changed that to `ActionBarActivity` and :

```
getFragmentManager();
```

to

```
getSupportFragmentManager();
```

I get an error as:

```
 512-512/ir.tsms.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:58)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:97)
            at ir.tsms.app.tsms.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:46)
```

Log cats:

```
  cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getSupportFragmentManager()`  

  cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getFragmentManager()`
```

Comment: post some code so that we can help you

Comment: I suggest you that when you want to create a new android project, uncheck "Create Activity" option available in New Android Application wizard. After creating project you have to manually create package name and you have to specify activity and and intent filters manually. In this case android.support.v7 will not be added automatically.

Comment: @AshishTiwari are you have simple sample like with that? i can not resolve problem

Comment: This example(http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer) has a best sample, I have tried this. It does not require any extra things to modify. Just download and import it on your workspace properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity should extends `FragmentActivity` o you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` (on older device)  if you are targeting only newer device use (extend `Activity`): `getFragmentManager()`